# how to get sub items using parent item's condition in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There are two tables.

**tbl_orders**

```
id, user_id, order_name, order_date
```

**tbl_order_items**

```
id, order_id, item_name, item_price
```

From these two tables, I need to get order items using a Laravel eloquent query, and I need to pull out the condition with a user_id of 1.

I want data using affiliation rather than DB queries or joins.
please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have one to many relationship between `orders` and `order_items` as below in your Model classes as mentioned in the [`Laravel docs`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

**Order.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model{
    protected $table = 'orders';
    public function order_items(){
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItems::class);
    }
}
```

**OrderItems.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderItems extends Model{
    protected $table = 'order_items';
    public function order(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller code:**

In your method, you can just do as:

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get(); // or any user ID you like
foreach($orders as $order){
   foreach($order->order_items as $o_item){
      // rest of the code goes here
   }
}
```